# Salesforce Process Builder Error myVariable_current.Account.Name because it hasn't been set or assigned

Tags: process-builder

I keep getting an error on my process "myVariable_current.Account.Name because it hasn't been set or assigned."

This first part of my process works.  But the second part I have a custom field on my case object Serial_Number__c. I have the following conditions below.

[image: Conditions]

When a case is edited with no account information that's when i get the error. I have a lookup field on the serial number object called Install_Account_Name__c. If there is no serial number on the case page don't update the install account field.

[image: no update]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to initiate process when Serial Number is not defined:

```
[Case.Serial_Number__c] is null Boolean True
```

And updating `[Case].Serial Number.Install Account Name`

But Serial Number does not exist, Install Account Name field **is not accessible**

Try to change first part Boolean to False:

```
if Serial Number is not empty -> update Serial Number.Install Acc Name
```

Also you can build formula like:

```
NOT(ISNULL([Case].Serial_Number__c ))
```

Comment: llya, thank you so much for your help. Your idea worked!!!